# Is there any way that I can have different methods of a partial class split among different folders and use a correct namespace convention?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class like this:

```
namespace Test.DataService
{
    public partial class DataManager
    {
        public int GetDeckA() { };
        public int GetDeckB() { };
        public int GetCarA() { };
        public int GetCarB() { };
```

As there are two different things involved I would like to split this so that these methods are split into two different files Deck.cs and Car.cs in two different folders:

**Folder Deck, filename Deck.cs**

```
namespace Test.DataService.Deck
{
    public partial class DataManager
    {
        public int GetDeckA() { };
        public int GetDeckB() { };
```

**Folder Car, filename Car.cs**

```
namespace Test.DataService.Car
{
    public partial class DataManager
    {
        public int GetCarA() { };
        public int GetCarB() { };
```

In the actual code it's much more complicated but I hope this is a good example.  Can anyone suggest how I can split a class or methods of a class into files in two different folders and still maintain the correct naming convention for the namespace?  I think I can do this if I put them both in the Namespace Test.DataService but then that's really not the correct namespace to use if the two files are in different folders.

Is there any way that I could move those methods into a different class that was part of DataManager and that I could easily access as that might solve the problem for me.  I suppose the issue there would be that I would have to create a new instance of the classes. Could I do that in the constructor of DataManager?

Comment: This would be perfectly correct. The logical naming (namespaces) and physical naming (files) are completely not related in C# (in contrast to Java which possibly gives you an impression that there are some restrictions).

Comment: You can put the files in different folders but the namespace is part of their identity. A convention that I use is that I name folders with a trailing underscore to indicate that I need to remove that part of the namespace declaration, e.g. "Deck_" and "Car_". (I also wrote an analyzer to present a warning and a code fix to remove it for me.)

Comment: as Wiktor mentioned namespaces have nothing to do with folders, so you can easily have your files in different folders while still being in the same namespace.

Comment: I just added some comment to the suggestion but not sure if that can help me.  I am just looking for some ideas.  I do so far like the Deck_ and Car_ suggestion.

Comment: This part *I am looking for some ideas* sounds like you need something subjective that somehow fits you better that something else. For this to work, you'd have to narrow your requirements somehow.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to create a partial class with parts in different namespaces. Namespaces are what allow us to have two or more distinct classes with the same name that do not conflict with each other and are distinct from each other.

Two classes with the same name in different namespaces are as separate from each other as two classes with different names in the same namespace. That's pretty much what namespaces are for.

You can put parts of a class in different folders. But your question specifies that you want to follow the convention of namespaces matching folders, which means the partial class would have to exist in two namespaces which is impossible.

Comment: Is there any way that I could access these methods in a sub class or something like that?

Comment: I would start by just putting methods in different classes without worrying about namespaces, partial classes, or subclasses. Then as needed one class can call the methods of another class.

Answer (score 1):

No, and this is a good thing. Classes, functions, modules, namespaces are good ways to organize the code for not "being lost" a few weeks later. On the list of the referenced namespaces, one can see how coupled (or decoupled) a class is. On the behaviour (public methods) the class is making public one can see what the responsibility of this class is. When reading the file one can see what the level of cohesion of the internals (fields, methods) of the class is. When splitting all this (behaviour, state, private methods) all the readability is lost.

It has to be a reason why this DataManager has to "live" in 2 namespaces. One reason could be that it does too much. Why not split it into 2 different classes and give them a proper name if you are already at it (managers are generally a code smell)